# Has Anyone Seen or Fixed Sluggishness?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, display, 16.10, displaylink

I upgraded my XPS-13 (9350) from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 16.10 and added the latest DisplayLink driver so that I can connect a HannStar 27" display via the D1000 docking station.

The upgrade was probably the easiest I've ever done. I tend to make such upgrades only under duress and not when I'm under a deadline, but my kids  managed to make the system very ill (especially wrt sound output), and I decided, "What the hell."

I seem to be seeing something like what the header to this thread describes.

If I have Chrome in full screen mode on the HannStar display and run youtube it looks like the old slow scan video of 1980s teleconferencing (one frame every 1/12th second or slower).

The mouse and pull down menus become extremely sluggish.

If I take Chrome out of full screen mode on the HannStar display but leave it in non-full screen mode on the HannStar display, everything is fine.

Chrome behaves without problem in full screen and non-full screen modes on the built-in display.

Firefox does not have any problem on the built-in display or on the HannStar display connected via the D1000 docking station.

At this point I don't have time to analyze whether the problem is in Chrome, Unity, DisplayLink, the hardware drivers, or something else.

Here is what lsusb tells me about the video hardware.

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 540 [8086:1926] (rev 0a)
DeviceName: Onboard IGD

When I get the chance, I will start the analysis with Chrome, but so much changed with the upgrade, that I may be looking for a needle in the haystack.

Comment: As 16.10 is a fairly new release, it may take a while for ***all*** important drivers to be published to 16.10 officially. (just a thought)

Comment: Here is the rest of what I have seen today.

 - I have experimented some more with Chrome. The sluggishness does not
   go away complete in non-full screen mode. It merely diminishes.
   
   Totem movie player exhibits the same problem as Chrome, there is no
   difference in behavior between full screen and non-full screen mode.

Comment: I see sluggishness often. Coffee always fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing.  I had the DisplayLink driver installed but I didn't need it.

If you install ccze and then run:

```
tailf /var/log/syslog | ccze
```

you may see your problem.

In my case the DisplayLink driver was failing and restarting constantly.  I uninstalled the DisplayLink driver but this didnt stop the behavior.  I then 'rm' from /etc/ and that stopped the driver from showing up.

This improved the performance of my machine.  I still feels sluggish and I if use it without docking it - I can tell that it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Creating or editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf to contain the following solves the problem I was seeing.

[Note I also upgraded Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit and am using version v1.3.52 of DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu. The system now works great with the D1000 docking station.]

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Intel Graphics"
Driver "Intel"
EndSection
```